# Cross browser text gradient in pure css without using background image

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have tried a lot for text gradient. I have found the code for safari and chrome but it is not compatible in other browsers. I want to make it work without using the background image. If u have any proper solution, kindly provide.

Comment: Closed: needs to be more focused: This should be protected by community, not closed x) ...

Answer (score 35):

I found the best way to do this is to use SVG gradients, it's easy to do and doesn't require any images, below is some code that creates a simple text gradient using SVG.

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#FF6600;stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-coloR:#FFF000;stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <text fill="url(#grad1)" font-size="60" font-family="Verdana" x="50" y="100">
    SVG Text Gradient</text>
    </svg>
```

You can change the x and y values to create a horizontal/vertical or diagonal gradient, you can also apply styles to it using a CSS stylesheet, all it takes is an extra line of code between the defs tags.

```
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
```

This method works in the latest versions of Chrome, IE, Firefox and Safari. You can also apply radial gradients, blurs and filters, for more information go to [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp).

Comment: ＋１  a thorough, cross-browser, dynamic-text and design-independent solution.

Comment: I found this solution years ago and it is sadly still as of 2020 the best solution I've found - the most crossbrowser && doesn't rule out other styles, like `text-shadow` because it's not a background "hack". `background-clip: text` support is better now, but it is still not full support and as I said, it's a workaround https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_background-clip_text

Comment: @Not sure what the case was like in 2020, but all browsers seem to support `background-clip:text` in 2023.

Answer (score 26):

```html
 <style type="text/css">
  h1 {
   font-family: "Myriad Pro", sans-serif;
   font-size: 40px;
   font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  /* --- start of magic ;-) --- */
  .white-gradient {
   position: relative;
  }
  .white-gradient:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 );
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0)));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
   background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
   background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
   background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
   background:         linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  }
  /* --- end of magic ;-) --- */
 </style>
 
 <h1 class="white-gradient">Pure CSS text gradient without any graphics</h1>
```

Comment: You should point out that this only works on white backgrounds, great solution though!

Comment: Not only white, as you can change colors in the provided css. However, gradient color has to be the same, as the color of the text background.

Comment: Commenting on kind of an old question, but is there any way to hide that white background?

Comment: As @SoulReaver said, this only works for fading text into or out of a solid color background. This example is not able to fade the text from red to black while keeping the background white.

Comment: run the code snippet, wonder why "graphics" is black

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with jQuery plugins.

The Cufon plugin may have it too, you should check that out.
It could also be done with the Raphael plugin or SVG and VML but a pure CSS cross-browser solution is hard to find.

Only for Chrome and Safari:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
    from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,.5)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));
```

For the rest of the browsers you have to use some JavaScript.

Comment: The link’s dead. Do you have any alternative? Also, what’s “cufon plugin”?