# Cross browser CSS 3 text gradient

Tags: html, css

On my website, I'm using a text gradient for the heading, but it only works on Chrome and probably Safari (although I haven't tested it), below is the code I'm using for the gradient. I was wondering whether there was a way to achieve the same/similar effect that would work across all 3 browsers?

```
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

**EDIT:** The problem with the other solution that's been posted is that it only works on a white background, as someone said in the comments, which is no good for me as I'm using a grey background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005447/cross-browser-text-gradient-pure-css-without-using-background-image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384751/css-text-gradient

Apparently it's a webkit thing

Comment: What do you mean "across all 3 browsers"? There are more than three browsers on the market in common use.

Comment: Yeh, but I'm only really bothered about IE, Chrome and Firefox as they're the main three

Comment: IE has a large user base. You should worry about it. Especially as it's perfectly capable of doing CSS gradients (certainly IE10 and later have complete support for the standards, and even older versions can do gradients with just a little bit of effort).

Comment: ah, I misread you.  :)  But the same applies to Safari too; you absolutely need to support it, otherwise you're ignoring every iPad user.

Comment: Good point, since both Chrome and Safari are webkit, then if it works on Chrome it should work on Safari as well, right?

Comment: @Spudley it only has a large user-base because people keep supporting it :)

Comment: Why wouldn't it work on gray?

Comment: It "works" but it just doesn't look good as there is a white stripe behind the heading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this to work in non-WebKit browsers, you need to use a solution other than CSS.

There are some JavaScript solutions out there, or you can use SVG.

Here's a good blog post on how to do it: http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/

Using JavaScript has the downside of... using JavaScript, but at the end of the day this is only a decorative visual effect.

Comment: SVG was the answer in the end

Answer (score 1):

-moz-background-clip:text does not work on firefox, and you won’t be able to achieve clipping effect in Firefox.

You can use [cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) for the text gradients, and thay will work on IE, Chrome and Firefox

Comment: This changed for Firefox 49+, it is now fully supported by FF and Edge, other browsers still needs prefix though https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_background-clip_text