# css linear gradient effect for all browser

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am new in stackoverflow. This is my first question. I am having an issue in css liner gradiant. 
I have this css:

```
.body-middle{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    background: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #353535, transparent);

    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 1px auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 2%;

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,180deg, transparent, #353535, transparent));
}
```

and this html:

```
<div class="body-middle"></div>
```

Currently it is perfectly working in firefox. It is not working in google chrome,safari and ie(also need to support in ie8).

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/c2xy4orq/)

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Though your specific question is already answered just a hint - google for css gradient generator, then you'll find some links where you can easily generate css gradient for all browsers.

Comment: it is not looking same in chrome as firefox

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross browser text gradient in pure css without using background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005447/cross-browser-text-gradient-in-pure-css-without-using-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
.box_gradient {
  background-color: #444444;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10-25, iOS 5+, Safari 5.1+ */
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
```

EDIT: Don't forget to give it a height and width to the div. Also you can see an example here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Go to "try it your self".

I think this will help you.

P.S. You can see the compatible versions of browsers too. IE9 and below does not support gradient!

Comment: Thanks but still it is just like a line no gradient in chrome

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
margin: auto auto;
}
.gradient-1 {
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(57, 81, 117, 1) 0%, rgba(46, 66, 93, 1) 45%, rgba(32, 47, 66, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(57, 81, 117, 1) 0%, rgba(46, 66, 93, 1) 45%, rgba(32, 47, 66, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(57, 81, 117, 1) 0%, rgba(46, 66, 93, 1) 45%, rgba(32, 47, 66, 1) 100%);
    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#395175", endColorstr="#202f42", GradientType=1);
}
.gradient-2 {
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, red, green);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, red, green);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,red, green);
    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff0000", endColorstr="#00ff00", GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-1"></div>
<div class="gradient-2"></div>
```

```css
.gradient{
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(57, 81, 117, 1) 0%, rgba(46, 66, 93, 1) 45%, rgba(32, 47, 66, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(57, 81, 117, 1) 0%, rgba(46, 66, 93, 1) 45%, rgba(32, 47, 66, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(57, 81, 117, 1) 0%, rgba(46, 66, 93, 1) 45%, rgba(32, 47, 66, 1) 100%);
    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#395175", endColorstr="#202f42", GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```